# How to create enum from a String

Tags: swift, enums, swift2

In Swift 2, can you create an enum from a string?

```
enum Food : Int { case Pizza, Pancakes }
let str = "Pizza"
let food = Food(name:str)   // for example
```

That last line doesn't work, but I'm looking for something like it. Like in Java, you can say `Food.valueOf("Pizza")`.

**Edit**: I can't use a String as a raw value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an initializer for the enum that takes a `String` as a parameter. From there, you switch over the string to set the value of self to a specific case like so:

```
enum Food: Int {
    case None, Pizza, Pancakes


    init(string: String) {
        switch string {
        case "Pizza":
            self = .Pizza
        default:
            self = .None
        }
    }
}

let foo = Food(string: "") // .None
let bar = Food(string: "Pizza") // .Pizza
```

Comment: As far as I know this is the best way using an Int enum rather than a String enum, but a better way may exist.

Comment: Oddly, my init(name:String) hides the the init(rawValue:Int), in project source, but not in playgrounds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742475/why-initrawvalue-not-callable-for-some-enums

Comment: @RobN we cannot achieve what you want via utilising reflection or rawValue. I think this answer is the best one .

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a compiler around to check the details but something like:

```
enum Food { case Pizza="Pizza", Pancakes="Pancakes" }
let str = "Pizza"
let food = Food(rawValue:str)
```

Comment: OK, seen your edit that this is not what you need. I will leave it here as possible info for others though.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up Enums where the raw value is a string, and then create an enum by specifying a raw value. That's close to what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ian's answer is great but, according to your needs, you may prefer an enum with a failable initializer:

```
enum Food: Int {

    case Pizza, Pancakes

    init?(name: String) {
        switch name {
        case "Pizza":       self = .Pizza
        case "Pancakes":    self = .Pancakes
        default:            return nil
        }
    }

}

let pizzaString = "Pizza"
let food = Food(name: pizzaString) // returns .Pizza (optional)
print(food?.rawValue) // returns 0 (optional)
```