# Why init(rawValue:) not callable for some enums?

Tags: swift, swift2

Anyone know why this works in a playground, but in a normal source files, gives this error: `/Incorrect argument label in call (have 'rawValue:', expected 'name:')` Maybe it's a bug.

```
enum Foo : Int {
    case A, B, C

    init?(name:String) {
        switch name {
        case "A": self = .A
        case "B": self = .B
        case "C": self = .C
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}

let foo2 = Foo(rawValue:2)!
```

**Edit**: I've noticed it works fine or Mac OS. I'm only seeing this if it's compiling for iOS.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in a compiled project.

Comment: Did you use the brand new Swift 2 (Xcode 7 beta)? I put in the tag but should mention it more prominently in the question.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and I did :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in both compiled project and a playground.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works in Swift 2; Xcode 7b1.

Comment: Might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390989/swift-enum-with-custom-initializer-loses-rawvalue-initializer

Comment: Looks like it. I just noticed it works for Mac targets for me, but not iOS.